# How can I attach a file with a PHP cURL XML Call

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm using the Amazon AIMS API to upload a an inventory file and I'm having an issue with the cURL call to upload the file. The documentation is very limited, so there is no example code that helps out in this.

This is what I have so far of the cURL call:

```
// $FILENAME is filename of the CSV file being uploaded:

$inventory = fopen($FILENAME, 'r') or die("Can't open file!");
echo $inventory;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $inventory);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ''); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($filename));
curl_setopt($ch, CUROPT_PUT, TRUE);


$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I've try putting $inventory into the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and not having an INFILE, but I get the same error.

On the XML response, I'm getting "`NO_FILE_ATTACHED`" so the obvious issue is getting the file to be attached to the XML call.

I also tried uploading as the first responder said using the Example #2 on the curl_setopt page on php.net.

For that, I used the following code:

```
$data = array('@/tmp/amazon_export.csv');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 


$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I got the same `NO_FILE_ATTACHED` response back.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$hCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_PUT,            true);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER,         true);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, CURL_TIMEOUT_SECS);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_URL,            "$oMessage->url/att/$fid");
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $aCurlHeaders);
// TODO it could be possible that fopen() would return an invalid handle or not work altogether.  Should handle that
$fp = fopen ($finfo['tmp_name'], "r");
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_INFILE,         $fp);
curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE,     $finfo['size']);

$sResp = curl_exec($hCurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are combining `PUT` and `POST` in a single curl operation, which will not work. Refer to [example #2](http://php.net/manual/function.curl-setopt.php#function.curl-setopt.examples) of the [curl_setopt](http://php.net/curl_setopt) manual page for an example on how to upload a file using POST.

Comment: I'm still getting the same NO_FILE_ATTACHED error with this instead:

$data = array('@/tmp/amazon_export.csv');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 

Which is as in the example.

Answer (score 0):

you have $filename and $FILENAME, the filesize call should be in your case filesize($FILENAME)...

Hope thats helps